# File upload with CKEditor and Django

Tags: python, django, ckeditor

I am having trouble with implementing image upload in DJango and CKEditor.

Here is my code:
models.py

```
from django.db import models
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField

# Create your models here.
class post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # body = RichTextField()
    body = RichTextUploadingField('body')
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'posts/%Y/%m/%d', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from posts.models import post
from posts import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

app_name = 'posts'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^ckeditor_uploader/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
] 

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root= settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Whenever I access Post in Admin, I get this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /admin/posts/post/13/change/
Reverse for 'ckeditor_upload' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

It seems like an URL error but I am not sure what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

delete url(r'^ckeditor_uploader/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
Add to  ckeditor_uploader -> ckeditor

```
urlpatterns = [
    **url(r'^ckeditor/', include(ckeditor_uploader_urls)),**
]
```